# compute integral involving a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices

I am trying to compute an integral for something of the following form:

$$
\int Q(A) \  (y - Ax)^T\ (y-Ax)\  dA
$$

Here $y$ and $x$ are vector quantities and $A$ is an affine matrix. $Q(A)$ is a multivariate Gaussian probability distribution with some given mean and covariance over the parameters of the affine matrix $A$. I am really bad at this but can someone point out to me how I can attempt to solve an integral like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linearity of expectation. Note $(y-Ax)^T (y-Ax) = y^T y - A^T x^T y - y^T A x + x^T A^T A x$.

So, $E[(y-Ax)^T (y-Ax)] = y^T y - E[A]^T x^T y - y^T E[A] x + x^T E[A^T A] x$.

Then, $E[A], E[A^T A]$ can be written down from the [matrix normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution)'s form (or by relating it to the vector normal distribution).

Comment: Thank you for that very clear explanation!

Comment: I was looking through the wikipedia page and could not find the formula for extectation of the form $A^{T}A$ for matrix normals. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, it should be simple from the form for $E[X^TBX]$ and assuming $B$ is an identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, that is how you can calculate it.